# How to set reply to in emailJS , the nodejs mailer?

Tags: node.js, email

I was trying to send a mail using the library `emailjs` in my node app.Everything is working except that I am not able to figure out how to set the '`reply to`' property in the configuration.Here is my code

```
var email1   = require(node_path + "emailjs/email");

var server1  = email1.server.connect(mail_sever_conf);


//prepare the message
var msg1 = {
        from : 'myfrommail@gmail.com',
        to:'tomailid@gmail.com',
        subject: 'My App mail subject',
        text : 'Some mail content',
        replyTo : 'notification@myapp.com' //This is what I tried
        };          


        //send the email
        server1.send(msg1, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
```

I dont see how to set that in their [github page](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) either, can someone please help me?

Comment: Would switching to https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer be an option (they support reply-to header)

Comment: Okay, let me try that then :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
reply-to
```

https://github.com/eleith/emailjs/blob/master/smtp/message.js
Line : 93

They are just passing as Headers. So it should work.

---

This was resolved/commented on in an issue raised on the project: https://github.com/eleith/emailjs/issues/54